# Is there any of Special way of showing Tentative Tasks in a Gantt graph using Project Libre?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, project-management, software-design, libreoffice, gantt-chart

I'm documenting a Software Web Application Project Plan. The customers have sent us:

1) snapshots of the various Web pages, and

2) Change Request Snapshots of some existing Web pages that we already developed.

Also, they send us software functional requirements through various emails. In other words, the software functional reqs are scattered here and there in various emails.

I started writing a Software Web Application Project Plan for the Webpages that so far contains various tasks that pertain to changes in aesthetics, and content of the webpages.

I created a Gantt graph using Project Libre.  I listed out the various Tasks, Subtasks, work packages, etc., but is there any of showing Tentative Tasks? In other words, is there a way to ensure that other people who review the Gantt graph know that it is a tentative task?

The reason I'm asking is that the Customer is constantly  changing requirements which is quite common in software projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically just mark such tasks with some extra text in the task name, uppercasing this mark. E.g. "Task name - TENTATIVE".